# C# Adding Text to ListBox with unique value set for each text from Json in a "foreach" loop

Tags: c#, json, text, listbox

This is my code:

It works but I can only add the name.

```
       dynamic parsedArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(source);

           ListTeam100.Items.Clear();
           foreach (dynamic item in parsedArray.gameConfig.customTeam100)
           {
               ListTeam100.Items.Add(item.summonerName);
               ListTeam100.Refresh();
           }
```

And this is my json data:

```
   "customTeam100": [
     {
       "summonerId": 111196989,
       "summonerName": "Nananaa",
     },
     {
       "summonerId": 222296989,
       "summonerName": "NananaaB",
     },
     {
       "summonerId": 125411111,
       "summonerName": "NononooBA",
     }
     ]
```

When I press a button my ListBox (named ListTeam100) will be updated to:

```
Nananaa

NananaaB

NononooBA
```

which is fine, as I need to see the name.

My problem is that I have no clue how to give that display name its own value, when selected the appropriate summonerId must be copied somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class in that you can have properties value and text.

```
public class ListBoxItem
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

List<ListBoxItem> data = new List<ListBoxItem>();
data.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Value1" });
data.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Value2" });
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
listBox1.DataSource = data;
```

You can add single item also like this

```
ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
item.Text = "Value1";
item.Value = "1";
listBox1.Items.Add(item);
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
```

Comment: I recognize that answer from another thread, I did my research before asking.

This is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Is it? Please provide the link so that I can mark the question duplicate

Comment: I'm having a different problem, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I've updated it. (my problem was explained also on the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
            var status = await lcu.http_client.GetAsync(lcu.baseURL + "/lol-lobby/v2/lobby").ConfigureAwait(true);
            string source = await status.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            dynamic parsedArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(source);

            ListTeam100.Items.Clear();
            ListTeam200.Items.Clear();

            foreach (dynamic item in parsedArray.gameConfig.customTeam100)
            {

               if (item.summonerName == "") {

                    ComboboxItem itemb = new ComboboxItem();
                    itemb.Text = item.botId;
                    itemb.Value = item.summonerId;
                    ListTeam100.Items.Add(itemb);


                }
               if (item.summonerName != "") {

                    ComboboxItem itemb = new ComboboxItem();
                    itemb.Text = item.summonerName;
                    itemb.Value = item.summonerId;
                    ListTeam100.Items.Add(itemb);

                }

                ListTeam100.Refresh();
            }
```